# Why aren't byte arguments recognized as integers?

Tags: java, constructor, enums, arguments, byte

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Months {
    JAN(31),
    FEB(28),
    MAR(31),
    APR(30),
    MAY(31),
    JUN(30),
    JUL(31),
    AUG(31),
    SEP(30),
    OCT(31),
    NOV(30),
    DEC(31);

    private final byte DAYS; //days in the month

    private Months(byte numberOfDays){
        this.DAYS = numberOfDays;
    }//end constructor

    public byte getDays(){
        return this.Days;
    }//end method getDays
}//end enum Months
```

It gives me an error that says *"The constructor Months(int) is undefined"* although I am passing a valid byte arguments. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: you are passing in ints but your constructor requires bytes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest solution is to accept an `int` value

```
private Months(int numberOfDays){
    this.DAYS = (byte) numberOfDays;
}
```

BTW non-static fields should be in `camelCase` not `UPPER_CASE`

Also FEB has 29 days in some years.

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    // assume Gregorian calendar for all time
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}

public int getDays(int year) {
    return days + (this == FEB && isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I thought about that but I am just wondering why isn't the number passed as an argument recognized as a byte instead of an int?

Comment: About Feb has 29 days in the leap years that's a special case so I am dealing with that simply by Months.FEB.getDays() + 1;

Comment: @KareemMesbah You could have a `getDays(int year)` method.

Comment: But what has the `isLeapYear()` method lost in `Months` enum? Nice piece of code, but restricting the example to just the first 3 lines would have made the answer more precise.

Comment: @KareemMesbah You could clarify your question by editing it with your comment regarding "I am just wondering why isn't the number passed as an argument recognized as a bye instead of an it".

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess there's something quite wrong about the logic of your code because a leap year could be a century year that's divisible by 400 and thus divisible by 100 which your first part of the second condition will validate it as false. However, your code will work properly because the second part of the second condition will be true so the whole second condition will be true. That's just a thing that I have noticed. Please notify me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @KareemMesbah You could print out some example to check it is right not not, but it look right to be.  You want multiples of 4, but not multiples of 100 unless its a multiple of 400

Answer (score 7):

Those numbers are `int` literals. You'd have to cast them to `byte`:

```
 JAN((byte)31),
```

Comment: check what I have asked in a comment to Peter Lawrey please.

Comment: well, the compiler just doesn't do that. It only sees an `int` literal, and does not look further.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1) says the following regarding lexical integer literals:

> The type of a literal is determined as follows:
>
> - The type of an integer literal (§3.10.1) that ends with L or l is long (§4.2.1).
> - The type of any other integer literal is int (§4.2.1).

So it requires you to explicitly cast this integer literal to byte.